# Change a Parameter of another Code while running

Tags: python, function, import, chess

Hey i'm trying to edit a chess code. In the Engine the board is given in an array.

```
class GameState:

...
self.board = [['bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK', 'bB', 'bN', 'bR'],
['bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp', 'bp'],
['--', '--', '--', 'wQ', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--', '--'],
['wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp', 'wp'],
['wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'wB', 'wN', 'wR']]
...
```

in my main I'm importing this Board with import ChessEngine. Now i want to change the board in the Engine via serial input. So i wrote this code:

```
    def brett(self):
            ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)
            ser.flush()
            while True:
                if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                    Brett = [ser.readline().decode('ascii').rstrip()]
                    return Brett
```

And i wrote   `self.board = self.brett()`
In my Main imported the function with

```
game_state = ChessEngine.GameState()
...
    while running:
        human_turn = (game_state.white_to_move and player_one) or (not game_state.white_to_move and player_two)
        game_state.brett()
...
```

Somehow i'm receiving errors like: `referenced before assignment error`  or  `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Somebody knows where the Problem is? Maybe i'm using the imports false. Is it possible to change a parameter in the Chessengine file the way i do?

Comment: Why is there a main-guard inside the `brett` method? Is it necessary? In case it is not the `__main__` file, `self.brett()` will return `None`

Comment: @cyttorak oh no i forgot to take it out, its not necessary. Sadly the error occurs without it too